# Why Commit size is somtimes less than working set ( windows memory)

Tags: windows, memory-management

Reading through MSDN docs, Working set is the amount of virtual memory currently residing in physical memory.

Commit size is the amount of virtual memory that can be backed by physical memory or disk page when application request access to virtual memory pages not used yet.

Now the thing I don't get how your commit size can be less than working set because you have physical memory mapped to virtual memory so that bare minimum they should be equal.

If you open task manager you would see an application that has a bigger working set than commit size.

Comment: Not every memory is comitted by you. If you map e.g. large amounts of shared memory or load many dlls which are also mapped into your process working set you can have large amounts of working set but only a small amount of committed memory.